# Using the SUPR-Q as a UX metric

Tags: metrics, questionnaire, nps

I was setting up a UX questionnaire for an e-Commerce site and liked the idea of the SUPR-Q questionnaire as a UX metric. I then read in an article that it's not free? How is this - is this correct? Does someone actually own the intellectual property on a questionnaire? If so, what's to stop me creating my own similar questions to ask?

Answer (score 5):

While Jeff and Measuring U do own the rights, they also say "*You are welcome to use the SUPR-Q questions without purchasing the SUPR-Q license. Please simply cite this reference [(Sauro, 2015)](http://uxpajournal.org/supr-q-a-comprehensive-measure-of-the-quality-of-the-website-user-experience/)*"

What you miss out on by not purchasing is the calculator and the industry benchmarks.

For more details visit [MeasuringU](https://measuringu.com/product/suprq/) website.